# Is there anyway to close Admob rewardAds after 5 seconds?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-console

I searched a lot and couldn't find anything to close rewardedAd after 5 seconds, the users have to watch until videoAd finish. Play store rejected my app from publishing because of this. This is the message from play console `Ads that interfere with normal app use that aren’t closeable after 5 seconds.`

I couldn't find no way to close rewardedAds before finish. I use Admob network ads in my app. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue. I don't want to remove the rewardAds instead I am looking for a solution.

Comment: I haven't asked anything  illegal. I meant, maybe there is a way that I don't aware of. even though if I ask for something which violates the Admob, they won't allow it.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have retracted my Vote to Close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that rewardedAds not skippable. The work around for this is to use rewardedInterstitialAd instead.